# accessing child fields in abstract class throught reflection in java

Tags: java, inheritance, reflection, field

I have 2 classes:

```
public abstract class AbstractTestClass {
    private String abstractString = "abstract";
    public void showFields() throws IllegalAccessException{
        for (Field field : this.getClass().getDeclaredFields()) {
            System.out.println(field.get(this));
        }
    }
}

public class TestClass extends AbstractTestClass {
    private String concreteString = "concreteString";
}
```

And test:

```
public class MainTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IllegalAccessException{
        TestClass test = new TestClass();
        test.showFields();
    }
}
```

Running this test causes next exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalAccessException: Class AbstractTestClass can not access a member of class TestClass with modifiers "private"
```

When i'm debuging code, this contains instance of TestClass.

Questions:

1. Why does it happen?
2. How to make this code work, not using Field.setAccessible() or changing visibility of fileds?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you are making the same mistake I made when I was starting out: that the abstract class and the extending class are two piece welded together to form a single class with access to all of each others fields and methods etc.

Sadly, this is not true: inheritance is a closer relationship that in a normal parent-child object, but access rules must still be obeyed e.g. if a method is declared `protected` in the abstract class and the extending class is in a different package, then it cannot be accessed (and vice versa).

Because the method `showFields()` is defined in `AbstractTestClass`, it can only access the fields in that class. Fields in `TestClass` are essentially walled off.

The only way around it that I can think of is to override `showFields()` in `TestClass`, swallow any exceptions about not being able to access private fields, then call `super.showFields()` and swallow any exceptions again. Not pretty.

```
public abstract class AbstractTest {
  private String abstractString = "abstract";
  public void showFields() throws IllegalAccessException {
    for (Field field : this.getClass().getSuperclass().getDeclaredFields()) {
      try {
        System.out.println(field.get(this));
      }
      catch (IllegalAccessException e) { 
        // swallow 
      }
    }
  }
}

public class MyTest extends AbstractTest
{
  private String concreteString = "concreteString";
  @Override public void showFields() throws IllegalAccessException {
    for (Field field : this.getClass().getDeclaredFields()) {
      try {
        System.out.println(field.get(this));
      }
      catch (IllegalAccessException e) {  
        // swallow
      }
    }
    super.showFields();
  }
}
```

I doubt this is what you had in mind...

Comment: *disclaimer:* I've managed to avoid using reflection for many years now and I'm a happier many for it. I'm even finding myself using extending classes less and less, preferring to use interfaces and delegating methods instead - so please don't consider my answer to be authoritative in any way.

Comment: A agree that reflection should be avoided, but try to experiment with self written annotations. So i must use them. Thanks for answer. I solved this problem changing visibility of fields to package. This package contains only abstract class and his children, so i think that won't be bad style.

Comment: Yeah, a good package structure and thoughtful use of access levels is always a better idea than resorting to hackery.

Answer (score 0):

> How to make this code work, not using Field.setAccessible() or changing visibility of fileds?

You can't, you have to make the field accessible to use it

Comment: Can you explain why? I was thinking like that: when i extend abstract class, then all his non abstract methods become methods of concrete class and when i am calling them they will be called from concrete class. And that in debug **this** contains concrete class embarrasses me.